# What will be the xUnit test case for Create method in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

Here is my code to create a new record in ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Code: (CreateController.cs file)

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddEmployeeViewModel addEmp)
        {
            var employee = new Employee()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Name = addEmp.Name,
                    Email = addEmp.Email,
                    Salary = addEmp.Salary,
                };
                await mvcDemoDbContext.Employees.AddAsync(employee);
               await mvcDemoDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

How to write xUnit test case for this particular method?

I have a created a separate xUnit Test project and create a controller instance in Arrange block.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below followed the two documents: [doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking),[doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0),hopes could help

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestFor_RedirecForTestAction_WhenModelStateIsValid()
        {
            //Arrange
            var employee = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "SomeName" };
            var mockset = new Mock<DbSet<Employee>>();
            var mockcontext = new Mock<MVCProjForTestContext>(new DbContextOptions<MVCProjForTestContext>());
            mockcontext.Setup(x=>x.Employee).Returns(mockset.Object);
            var controller = new HomeController(mockcontext.Object);

            //Act
            var result=await controller.RedirecForTest(employee);

            //Asssert

            mockset.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Employee>(), default(CancellationToken)), Times.Once());
            mockcontext.Verify(x=>x.SaveChangesAsync(default(CancellationToken)), Times.Once()) ;
           
            var redirectresult =Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
            Assert.Null( redirectresult.ControllerName);
            Assert.Equal("Index", redirectresult.ActionName);
        }
    }




public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private readonly MVCProjForTestContext _context;

        public HomeController(MVCProjForTestContext context)
        {
            _context=context;
        }
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> RedirecForTest(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _context.Employee.AddAsync(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    
}


public class MVCProjForTestContext : DbContext
    {
        public MVCProjForTestContext (DbContextOptions<MVCProjForTestContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<MVCProjForTest.Models.Employee> Employee { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

The result:

[image]